# Adding integers with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, int, memory-address, addition

Say i have `int *a, int *b, int *c` and say `a` and `b` already point to some integers.

I want to add the integers down `a` and `b` and save them to wherever `c` is pointing to

This:

```
*c = *a + *b;
```

does not work.  It always spits out "invalid argument of 'unary *'.  Why so?

ADDITIONAL INFO:
here's how I'm trying to implement it:

```
int getCoordinates(int argc, char *argv[], FILE *overlay, FILE *base, int *OVx, int *OVy, int *OVendx, int  *OVendy, int *Bx, int *By, int *Bendx, int *Bendy) 
{

     ... // OVx and OVw are assigned here.  I know it works so I won't waste your time with this part.

     // Set overlay image's x and y defaults (0,0).
     *OVx = 0;
     *OVy = 0;
     ...

     OVendx = (*OVx) + (*OVw);
     OVendy = (*OVy) + (*OVh);
```

Comment: It works on my machine. What problem exactly are you having?

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning the values correctly? [This example](http://ideone.com/aRFAt) works fine. (Notice you have to dereference the pointer to see the value. You might not be doing this.)

Comment: That works perfectly.  Post a complete example that illustrates the problem, as well as your expected and observed behavior.

Comment: Have you initialized the pointer `c` to point to a valid memory location ?

Comment: @Mahesh: an excellent suggestion.

Comment: It appears you need to dereference your assignment: *OVendx = (*OVx) + (*OVw); Your version is just moving the pointer.

Comment: The code you posted contains no instances of the form you say you are getting an error with. Please post the actual code that gets the "invalid argument of 'unary *'" message and point out which line gets the error. If you want help, you need to be helpful yourself.

Comment: "// OVx and OVw are assigned here.  I know it works so I won't waste your time with this part."  Time after time, people post questions here with comments like that and it's the omitted code that is the problem.

Comment: O LOL I see now!  It was a typo/misread on my part.  OVw and OVh are ints not pointers! Haha!

Comment: Some of us suspected as much. Again, when posting questions, please don't leave out the critical lines that identify the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 0;
    int *a = &x;
    int *b = &y;
    int *c = &z;

    *c = *a + *b;

    printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", *a, *b, *c );
    return 1;
}
```

Running yields:

```
./a.out 
1 + 2 = 3
```

Common errors you might have encountered:

1. Not pointing a, b or c at valid
   memory.  This will result in your program crashing.
2. Printing the value of the
   pointer (a) rather than the value it
   points to (*a).  This will result in a very large number being displayed.
3. Not dereferencing the assignment c = *a + *b rather than *c = *a + *b. In this case, the program will crash when you try to dereference c after the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

If Ovendx, Ovendy are pointing to a valid memory locations, then to assign values to that location, you need to dereference them. So, it should be -

```
(*OVendx) = (*OVx) + (*OVw);
(*OVendy) = (*OVy) + (*OVh);
```

You aren't dereferencing in the snippet posted.